# C to C++ error at function call

Tags: c++, c, assembly, gdb

I am trying to convert a c program to c++. This program generates a set of "*.so" files which is used in another program generated by llvm. Basically the llvm generated code has callbacks to the current code. I am loading these by using LDPRELOAD

As a first step I am just compiling the code with c++. The compilation was working fine. But when run it segfaults. There is a label `dec_blk` which is supposed to contain the address of a function `dec_blk()`. I have use `extern "C"` for that function and its prototype to prevent demangling. When it is run with c version, the label has the right address but, when I run it with c++ version the value of that label is 0. I am providing the details below

**LLVM code**

```
subq    $24, %rsp
movq    dec_blk, %rax
movq    dec_blk+8, %rcx
movq    %rdi, 16(%rsp)
movq    %rcx, %rdi
movq    16(%rsp), %rcx
movq    %rsi, 8(%rsp)
movq    %rcx, %rsi
movq    8(%rsp), %rdx
callq   *%rax # segfaults here
```

**function declaration**

```
extern "C"
{
long int dec_blk(void*, long int*, long int* );
}
```

Could you please help on what to look for. I am using gdb to debug

Comment: So your problem is solved?

Comment: @phresnel Nooooooooooooooooo :(

Answer (score 0):

> There is a label dec_blk which is supposed to contain the address of a function dec_blk(). ... but, when I run it with c++ version the value of that label is 0

Your description matches this code (which you didn't show):

```
extern "C" long int dec_blk(...);
int main() {
  return dec_blk();
}
```

But the disassembly in your question matches this (*different*) code instead:

```
extern "C" long int (*dec_blk)(...);
int main() {
  return dec_blk();
}
```

These two snippets are *not at all* the same. I am guessing that you've used the second function when you meant to use the first one.

Comment: @simpleuser "this is not the case". You checked *how*? You are unlikely to get a satisfying answer unless you provide additional details (and I *still* think that my hypothesis is most likely correct; at least that's what the compiled code looks like).